# When are denormals actually useful?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Whenever I search for the term 'denormal numbers' or 'denormals', I only find ways how to detect them and round them to zero. Apparently, nobody really likes them, because dealing with them incurs a performance penalty.

And yet, they're implemented everywhere. Why? If it's for precision, I'd say you're gonna need a bigger float, or change the order of your operations such that you avoid really small intermediate values. I find it hard to believe that that little bit of extra precision is really worth the precious clock cycles.

Are there any good reasons why one would still use denormal numbers? And if there are no significant reasons to have denormal numbers, why implement them at all? Only to have IEEE754 compliance?)

Comment: For reference, here's an example of how bad denormals can be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, because gradual underflow retains some useful mathematical identities (e.g. x-y == 0 means that x == y). Some explanations of why gradual underflow can be useful:

http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/faq.html#underflow

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ARITH_17U.pdf

And yes, in some cases underflows are encountered due to bad application design, and the proper action is to fix the application. In other cases applications that work correctly with gradual underflow would fail under abrupt underflow.

Furthermore,

- In many cases, slow but correct is considered a better default than fast but dangerous.
- Since gradual underflow is the default, google finds people complaining about that and wanting to turn it off. If OTOH abrupt underflow were the default, maybe instead you'd see more people complaining about mysterious numerical issues? Numerical programming is hard enough as it is!
- Modern hw has reduced the penalty for working with subnormal numbers. See e.g. http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=142&v=t

Comment: It looks like you meant 'abrupt' where you wrote 'gradual' at the end of your second paragraph.

Comment: "x-y == 0 means that x == y" Please explain [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334688/how-dangerous-is-it-to-compare-floating-point-values) then.

Comment: @Tinctorius: absolutely nothing on the page you linked to contradicts that.  More to the point, it is a basic *theorem* of floating-point error analysis (i.e. it is mathematically true); there is nothing to "explain".

Comment: I should have been more clear about it. What I meant was: please explain how that is a useful property, in the light of `x==y` or `x-y==0` being bad smells when doing FP calculations. You always need to know your margin of error (and don't forget error-on-error, or whatever it's called again), and comparisons should always be like `|x-y|<f(eps)` or `x+f(eps)<y`.

Comment: @Tinctorius: A "code smell" is an overly-coarse guideline for people who don't actually know what they're doing (or can't be bothered to carefully read the sources in question).  Exact FP comparisons (especially with zero) are both appropriate and correct in many circumstances; and are absolutely used by those who understand floating-point.

Comment: An example would be nice. I really can't find any, except for very, very safe numbers around one.

Answer (score 4):

Denormals are extremely useful; there are a number of useful error bounds on floating-point computation which are no longer true if you remove denormals (the most important being that `x-y == 0` if and only if `x == y`).

It's also important to remember that (a) denormals do not incur a penalty on *all* hardware; there exist systems which can handle denormals at speed (or very close to it) and (b) denormals only slow down your computation if you actually encounter one.  If you don't use them, you don't pay for them (and if you *do end up* using them, then your result would have likely been wrong without them--if you simply want a wrong answer as quickly as possible, you can replace your entire computation with `return 0`).

Comment: If you want a completely correct computation - use bignums. The reason you chose floating point, is to trade precision for efficiency. The same applies for choosing not to use denormals. Indeed you can instruct the compiler to disable them.

Answer (score 0):

when are they actually useful ? with a tiny bit of numeric-string formatting, you can do a very specific type of integer multiplication to full 2546-bit precision spanning 767 decimal digits without using any `bigint` libraries :

```
mawk '($++NF = sprintf("%.971g",
       __ = (__ = (_ = 4)^-_^_ * (_*_ + _*_)^-(--_ + --_)) * \
      (_^(___ = _+_ * ++_^_ - _--) - ___^_) * __))^(_=!_)' /dev/null | 

mawk NF=NF FS='^[+-]?0*|[.]|[Ee][+-]?[0-9]+$' OFS= | gfactor -h
```

---

> ```
> ( 2^53 - 53^2 ) :: prime mantissa        :: 9007199254738183
>         
> * ( 2^-537 )^2  :: denormalized exponent ::            -1074
> ```

---

```
4450147717013014935781297373122216146699265127089690208121111
1955111373994456919942086443016410324138877948439594767734600
7536130200074723901263493586735348385956170076834788225586871
0149848553243418642303155745857768066392178700185848375665128
6183187932225415240609383686118875212320163715549033691533037
4701932436869896231904002909185639280797110767721194314409888
1217775019873316067010633149112292451404615942454658064565101
3196980899131817300804181744883611272850174152498261912527633
9848161883339769210577524860725090013626969081174367749462595
5381589884432923914606931238647593865468520532049239161439367
3486883291686813158861578968854832701582723405942766297839566
1130263385441340464878930937622541158627259056070659673162714
93103840839467011392116546630859375:
        5^1074
        9007199254738183
```