# Can accessing uninitialized values result in a performance hit?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, micro-optimization, initialization

I'm optimizing a matrix numerical hotspot.

Currently, I'm doing blocking and [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) to improve performance. However, I deliberately avoid peeling the borders. Instead I let the blocking steps overflow, and of course, the algorithm then touches uninitialized values.

However, the matrix is generously pre-allocated to cope with the overflow so I am not actually illegally accessing a memory location.

I don't do peeling for several reasons:

- Laziness
- Performance hit due to the very bad locality of the peeling border case.
- To avoid complex border peeling code.

However, I am wondering whether these overflowed accesses that touch uninitialized value(s) would actually cause a performance hit?

I predictably know where the uninitialized accesses happen and they are also reported via valgrind. I have also profiled the code using Intel's VTune and could not see any signs that would point to a degraded performance due to this.

Comment: +1, I strongly suggest that you at least zero-initialize them. Assuming you're working with floating-point, uninitialized data has a high probability of being denormalized. [And you do not want that to mess up your performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x/9314926#9314926).

Comment: I know, but greedily zeroing out a pool of pre-allocated matrices with `memset` is very expensive too.

Comment: Though depending on how large your loops are, a penalty of a few hundred cycles at the end of each loop is probably not noticeable.

Comment: You don't have to initialize the entire dataset. Just the end points.

Comment: but the question is more whether I will get a performance hit by touching the uninitialized values ... a couple of errors in valgrind don't actually bother me unless there is a performance hit for the uninitialized value accesses.

Comment: *Loading* uninitialized values isn't going to hurt performance. But if you try to do any arithmetic on them, then it'll definitely hurt it turns out to be denormalized.

Comment: OK got it now thanks :) read your post, very nice!

Comment: @Mystical if you post an answer (even small one) I will accept it ... I am convinced with your argument of the denormalized flop so I will blank out the "ghost layer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to get pedantic stuff out of the way:

According to the standard, bad things can happen if you use uninitialized data. (The standard allows for "trap" values that could trigger exceptions.) But for all practical purposes, this probably doesn't apply here.

---

**If you're dealing with integers**, accessing and operating on uninitialized data will have no effect on performance. (aside from division, all operations are usually fixed latency)

**For floating-point**, there are two problems:

1. [Signalling NaNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Signaling_NaN)
2. [Denormalized Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number)

Depending on the environment, signalling NaNs may trigger a hardware exception. So this would actually be a correctness issue, not just a performance issue.

It may counter-intuitive that denormal floats have anything to do with this. However, 
*uninitialized data has a high probability of being denormalized*.

[And you really don't want to be messing with denormalized floating-point.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314534/why-does-changing-0-1f-to-0-slow-down-performance-by-10x)

So if you're unlucky enough for the uninitialized values to have even one denormalized value, you can expect a nasty 100+ cycle penalty at the end of each loop iteration. Now depending on how large the loops are, this may or may not matter.

That said, **why is uninitialized data prone to be denormalized?** If the first few bits of a floating-point value are zero, then it is denormalized. It's that easy. If the data used to be a integer, or a 64-bit pointer... It'll be denormalized when reinterpreted as a floating-point value.

---

Suggestions:

- Zero initialize the data. If it's too expensive, at least zero-initialize the end-points.
- Avoid accessing the uninitialized data by putting in that clean up code. Something like [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) might be appropriate. Though I generally prefer a set of binary reducing if-statements.