# Why some arithmetic operations take more time than usual?

Tags: c, performance, time

I've detected an unusual computational time when performing arithmetic operations with floating numbers of small precision. The following simple code exhibit this behavior:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_ITER = 100000000;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    double x = 1.0, y;
    int i;
    clock_t t1, t2;
    scanf("%lf", &y);
    t1 = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_ITER; i++)
        x *= y;
    t2 = clock();
    printf("x = %lf\n", x);
    printf("Time: %.5lfsegs\n", ((double) (t2 - t1)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

Here are two different runs of the program:

- With y = 0.5

  > x = 0.000000
  >   Time: 1.32000segs
- With y = 0.9

  > x = 0.000000
  >   Time: 19.99000segs

I'm using a laptop with the following specs to test the code:

- **CPU**: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T5800 @ 2.00GHz × 2
- **RAM**: 4 GB
- **OS**: Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits)
- **Model**: Dell Studio 1535

Could someone explain in detail why this behavior occurs? I'm aware that with y = 0.9 the x value goes to 0 more slowly than with y = 0.5, so I suspect the problem is directly related to this.

Comment: You're probably getting more denormals in the second case before you get to 0.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9314926/1011995) concerning performance implications of denormals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Denormal (or rather subnormal) numbers are often a performance hit. Slowly converging to `0`, per your second example, will generate more subnormals. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/d/entry/subnormal_numbers). For more serious reading, check out the oft-cited (and very dense) [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

From the second source:

> Under IEEE-754, floating point numbers are represented in binary as:
>
> `Number = signbit \* mantissa \* 2exponent`
>
> There are potentially multiple ways of representing the same number,
>   using decimal as an example, the number 0.1 could be represented as
>   1*10-1 or 0.1*100 or even 0.01 * 10. The standard dictates that the
>   numbers are always stored with the first bit as a one. In decimal that
>   corresponds to the 1*10-1 example.
>
> Now suppose that the lowest exponent that can be represented is -100.
>   So the smallest number that can be represented in normal form is
>   1*10-100. However, if we relax the constraint that the leading bit be
>   a one, then we can actually represent smaller numbers in the same
>   space. Taking a decimal example we could represent 0.1*10-100. This
>   is called a subnormal number. The purpose of having subnormal numbers
>   is to smooth the gap between the smallest normal number and zero.
>
> It is very important to realise that subnormal numbers are represented
>   with less precision than normal numbers. In fact, they are trading
>   reduced precision for their smaller size. Hence calculations that use
>   subnormal numbers are not going to have the same precision as
>   calculations on normal numbers. So an application which does
>   significant computation on subnormal numbers is probably worth
>   investigating to see if rescaling (i.e. multiplying the numbers by
>   some scaling factor) would yield fewer subnormals, and more accurate
>   results.

I was thinking about explaining it myself, but the explanation above is extremely well written and concise.

Answer (score 3):

You get a measurable difference not because `0.9^n` converges to 0 more slowly than `0.5^n` mathematically, but because in IEEE-754 floating-point implementations, it doesn't converge to 0 at all.

The smallest positive `double` in IEEE-754 representation is 2<sup>-1074</sup>, the smallest positive normal is 2<sup>-1021</sup>, so with `y = 0.5`, the loop encounters 53 subnormal numbers. Once the smallest positive subnormal is reached, the next product would be 2<sup>-1075</sup>, but due to the round-ties-to-last-bit-zero default rounding mode that is rounded to 0. (IEEE-754 *representation* of floating point numbers and the default round-ties-to-last-bit-zero rounding mode are pretty much ubiquitous on standard consumer hardware, even if the standard is not fully implemented.) From then on, you have a multiplication `0*y` which is an ordinary floating point multiplication (that one's fast even if `y` is a subnormal number).

With `0.5 < y < 1`, once you've reached the lower end of the (positive) subnormal range, the result of `x*y` rounds to the value of `x` again (for `y = 0.9`, the fixed point of the iteration is 5*2<sup>-1074</sup>). Since that is reached after a few thousand iterations (`0.9^7 < 0.5`), you're basically multiplying a subnormal number with a nonzero number for the entire loop. On many processors, such a multiplication can't be handled directly and has to be handled in microcode, which is a lot slower.

If speed is more important than IEEE-754 semantics (or if those are undesirable for other reasons), many compilers offer options to disable that behaviour and flush subnormal numbers to 0 if the hardware supports that. I couldn't find an option for explicitly that in my gcc's man page, but `-ffast-math` did the trick here.

Comment: Kudos for proving that is possible to analyze the problem with exact calculations and for providing a compiler option to optimize. Could you explain a bit more why, with 0.5 < y < 1, the product x * y rounds to x again if inside the subnormal range?

Comment: If `x` is the smallest positive subnormal, and `y > 0.5`, then the exact value of `x*y` is larger than `x/2`, so it's not a tie, and it's rounded to the closer of `x` and `0`, which is `x`. If `y` is sufficiently larger than 0.5, that happens before `x` reaches the smallest subnormal `s`, e.g. for `y = 0.75`, you have `(2*s)*y = 1.5*s` mathematically, that produces a tie - it's exactly half-way between `s` and `2*s`, so it gets rounded to `2*s` again which has the last bit 0. For `y = 0.9` and `x = 5*s`, you'd get `4.5*s`, but the closest `double` is slightly larger than 0.9, so it rounds up.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew about this low level details.