# Displaying 0 in loop

Tags: c++, c

Am trying to create simple while loop until my variable will be 0.
So am created a

```
do
{
x = x + 0.001;
cout << x0 << endl;
} while (SOME_CALCULATION != 0);
```

Everything works great until my loop reach 0 then i getting 7.63278e-017 instead of 0.

Loop example:

```
result: -0.003
result: -0.002
result: -0.001
result: 7.63278e-017
result: 0.001
result: 0.002
result: 0.003
```

Comment: That's normal and expected behaviour of floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Related: [Most effective way for float and double comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Comment: Can we assume that the use of two variables (`x` and `x0`), and the differences between the `cout` line and the reported results, in the fragment above are just typos?

Comment: Not a duplicate but certainly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698927/compare-double-to-zero-using-epsilon

Answer (score 3):

Do something like that:

```
    double epsilon = 0.00001; 
    do
    {
        x = x + 0.001;
        cout << x0 << endl;
    } while (abs(SOME_CALCULATION) > epsilon);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider rewriting this as

```
x = -3;

do
  {
  x = x + 1;
  cout << x0 / 1000 << endl;
  } while (SOME_CALCULATION != 0);
```

SOME_CALCULATION will need to be adjusted for the fact that `x` is now an integer rather than a fractional floating point value - perhaps replicating the `x0 / 1000` within the calculation would work.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Some real numbers cannot be represented exactly in floating point (for example, `1.0/3.0`). As a result, rounding errors are introduced, and can accumulate in surprising ways.  Check out [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for more information.

Depending on your algorithm, a simple workaround could be to check for `<=0` rather than `==0`.  In general, if you find yourself checking equivalency of a floating point value, you should think twice and ensure that all possible values are exactly representable using the type specified.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Used long or int variables and convert to double before output:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int x=-3;
    do
    {
        x = x + 1;
        cout << ((double)x)/1000 << endl;
    } while (x < 4);
}
```

Output:

```
-0.002
-0.001
0
0.001
0.002
0.003
0.004
```