# Dealing with 0.0 and -0.0, how to properly compare values

Tags: c++, double

I am working on function to determine if a circle and a ray intersect each other. The base of the function comes from [this website](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/) specifically [this page](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/raysphere.c). In the notes on the first page where the author discusses circle and ray intersection he lists this about determining if a circle and ray intersect

> The exact behavior is determined by the expression within the square
>   root b * b - 4 * a * c
>
> - If this is less than 0 then the line does not
>     intersect the sphere.
> - If it equals 0 then the line is a tangent to the sphere intersecting
>     it at one point, namely at u = -b/2a.
> - If it is greater then 0 the line intersects the sphere at two points.

This is where the problem in my code lies. It lies the comparison of the `double bb4ac` in the function below.

```
bool CircleRayIntersect(double ip1_x, double ip1_y, double ip2_x, double ip2_y,
                                double isc_x, double isc_y, double isc_r,
                                double &out1_x, double &out1_y,
                                double &out2_x, double &out2_y)
{
    double a,b,c; 
    double bb4ac;
    double r = isc_r;
    double dp_x;
    double dp_y;
    double mu_1;
    double mu_2;
    double p1_x = ip1_x;
    double p1_y = ip1_y;
    double p2_x = ip2_x;
    double p2_y = ip2_y;
    double sc_x = isc_x;
    double sc_y = isc_y;

    dp_x = p2_x - p1_x;
    dp_y = p2_y - p1_y;
    a = dp_x * dp_x + dp_y * dp_y;
    b = 2 * (dp_x * (p1_x - sc_x) + dp_y * (p1_y - sc_y));
    c = sc_x * sc_x + sc_y * sc_y ;
    c += p1_x * p1_x + p1_y * p1_y;
    c -= 2 * (sc_x * p1_x + sc_y * p1_y);
    c -= r * r;
    bb4ac = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    // Checks to make sure that the line actually intersects
    TRACE("  -- Checking     a: %f\n", a);
    TRACE("  -- Checking bb4ac: %f\n", bb4ac);

    if (abs(a) < 1E-9 || bb4ac < 0.0) 
    {

        if(bb4ac < 0.0)
        {
            TRACE("bb4ac is less than zero: %d < 0.0 = %d\n", bb4ac, (bb4ac < 0.0));
            TRACE("bb4ac is less than zero: %f < 0.0 = %f\n", bb4ac, (bb4ac < 0.0));
        }
        if (abs(a) < 1E-9)
            TRACE("abs(a) is less than zero\n");

        mu_1 = 0;
        mu_2 = 0;
        TRACE("Ray does not intersect with circle!\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    mu_1 = (-b + sqrt(bb4ac)) / (2 * a);
    mu_2 = (-b - sqrt(bb4ac)) / (2 * a);

    out1_x = p1_x + (mu_1*(p2_x-p1_x));
    out1_y = p1_y + (mu_1*(p2_y-p1_y));
    out2_x = p1_x + (mu_2*(p2_x-p1_x));
    out2_y = p1_y + (mu_2*(p2_y-p1_y));

    return TRUE;
}
```

At some points, when this code is called with certain arguments `bb4ac` ends up being equal to `-0.0`. When this happens the checking of `bb4ac` against the rules listed above becomes broken. Here is some sample output from the `TRACE` statements when `bb4ac` is `-0.0`.

```
  -- Checking     a: 129.066667
  -- Checking bb4ac: -0.000000
bb4ac is less than zero: 0 < 0.0 = -1114636288
bb4ac is less than zero: -0.000000 < 0.0 = 0.000000
```

Judging by the output of the `TRACE` it looks like the `if(..)` statement that compares `bb4ac` with `0` does not interpret `bb4ac` properly. Seeing that `bb4ac` is printed as `-1114636288` when interpreted with the `%d` flag and `-0.000` when interpreted with the `%f` flag, I would have to think that `bb4ac` is being interpreted into `-1114636288` in the `if` statement and not `-0.000`.

*How can I write the if statement to properly interpret `bb4ac` as `-0.000`? Why is it seeing it as that in the first place?*

Comment: You're messing up the types for `printf`, which is Undefined Behavior and often causes stack corruption. And since it's UB, none of your results are meaningful - technically not even those preceding the UB!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `TRACE` is a `printf`-like varargs function, using `%d` with a `double` argument, or `%f` with an `int` or `bool` argument is **undefined behavior**. Use the correct format specifiers or cast the argument to the correct type.

Comment: What is a varargs function? Variable arguments?

Comment: @AnotherUser like `printf`, using format specifiers to determine how to access variable argument: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments.

Comment: Does this answer mean my TRACE statements are altering the outcome of the comparison or is this just a side note? // If I want to print a double, I should use `%f`?

Comment: @AnotherUser "I would have to think that bb4ac is being interpreted into -1114636288 in the if statement" - the premise of your question is incorrect.

Comment: @AnotherUser if you want to print a double, you should use `%g`.

Comment: Could you pass me a source for that, not that I don't believe you. I just don't know anything about the format specifiers and I have never found something good.

Comment: @AnotherUser I would use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/printf - apologies if it's too terse.

Comment: Probably the reason I am here is because I like the terse.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are familiar with the fact that double comparison should never be precise(i.e. you should use tolerance), but you are not doing it quite right. To check if a number is less than zero:

```
if (x < -1E-9)
```

To check if a number is greater than zero:

```
if (x > 1E-9)
```

To check if a number is zero:

```
if (x > -1E-9 && x < 1E-9)
```

Comment: Actually, he might find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13698927/2508277) interesting.