# Denormalized numbers C#

Tags: c#

I recently came across denormalized definition and I understand that there are some numbers that cannot be represented in a normalized form because they are too small to fit into its corresponding type. According with IEEE

[image]

So what I was trying to do is catch when a denormalized number is being passed as a parameter to avoid calculations with this numbers. If I am understanding correct I just need to look for numbers within the Range of denormalized

```
private bool IsDenormalizedNumber(float number)
{
    return Math.Pow(2, -149) <= number && number<= ((2-Math.Pow(2,-23))*Math.Pow(2, -127)) ||
           Math.Pow(-2, -149) <= number && number<= -((2 - Math.Pow(2, -23)) * Math.Pow(2, -127));
}
```

Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Seems to be the right way to approach it. However, your formulas do not match the definition: `return Math.Pow(2, -149) <= number && number<= ((1-Math.Pow(2,-23))*Math.Pow(2, -126)) || Math.Pow(-2, -149) >= number && number >= -((1 - Math.Pow(2, -23)) * Math.Pow(2, -126))`

Comment: It feels wrong to me that you're using `double` calculations and `<=` operators to do the comparisons. I think there's more casting going on than a fishing carnival and that could make any of these comparisons fall over.

Comment: So, do you think I could be getting wrong comparisons because of the different formats I am getting with double and float ?

Comment: There's just no point waiting when your math model starts generating numbers that are nonsensical *and* inaccurate.  If you are computing a physical property, like a length, then you hit the emergency stop button well before it gets less than the diameter of an atom.  Which is 1E-10, no point letting get all the way to 1E-38.  If you don't know the *practical* range of the math model then ask whomever created it to add them.  Just as you need to know the accuracy of the calculation.  *float* has only 6 significant digits, if the calculation is convoluted then you may have none left.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant, I am curious to know what value there is in specifically detecting a denormalized number and what the use case is. If there are problems with underflows then go to a bigger data type. If that still doesn't work use a good software implemented numeric type. Usually for that I would use Maple where you can specify the exact number of digits of precision that you want for a calculation (using `Digits := x`). High precision comes at a performance cost though since computations will be in software rather than hardware, so it is best avoided if possible.

Comment: @ChiuneSugihara It makes sense if it is a tool that helps creating binary configurations based in some specifications, this hardware is not able to handle well denomalized numbers so I need to avoid the use of this format.

Comment: @Nandhi If you are using binary configurations why are you converting them to the .NET type system? That is just adding an extra layer of complexity that you don't need, especially since .NET types have added complexity in relation to binary layout. Is there really a need to involve the .NET type system if you already have a binary configuration and could just work directly with that? Also do you need to be concerned about little endian vs big endian storage formats since you are dealing with other systems?

Comment: @ChiuneSugihara in fact this tool is generating the configurations based in some inputs to then get the binary format to be able to load this into the hardware, that is why I need to avoid the denormalized numbers but you are right, I need also to care about the big endian and little endian.

Comment: @Nandhi The reason I ask about endianess is that `BitConverter` will assume a specific endianess for incoming bytes which can be found by checking `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`. You will need to make sure to take care not to have the bytes in the wrong order before converting to a .NET type otherwise you will get a wrong answer (not sure if you are doing that already or not). It would be simpler and more performant just to bitmask the bytes directly rather than involving the .NET type system and its complications.

Comment: @Nandhi Also it seems to me that you are dealing with denormalized numbers because you are taking bit patterns that aren't meant to be floats in the first place (since you refer to them as "configurations") and then trying  to send them into the hardware as a float. Is that correct?

Comment: @ChiuneSugihara, yes that's correct.

Comment: @Nandhi I see, so that would explain why you would be running into the denormalized numbers in a realistic scenario. It seems like there should be an alternative to having to send something that wasn't meant to be interpreted as a float to a location that will be interpreted as a float as this is ugly, but if this is the only way that was found to do whatever you are working on I now see why you are asking this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to inspect the bits. Normalized or denormalized is a characteristic of the binary representation, not of the value itself. Therefore, you will be able to detect it more reliably this way and you can do so without and potentially dangerous floating point comparisons.

I put together some runnable code for you, so that you can see it work. I adapted this code from a similar question regarding doubles. Detecting the denormal is much simpler than fully excising the exponent and significand, so I was able to simplify the code greatly.

As for why it works... The exponent is stored in offset notation. The 8 bits of the exponent can take the values 1 to 254 (0 and 255 are reserved for special cases), they are then offset adjusted by -127 yielding the normalized range of -126 (1-127) to 127 (254-127). The exponent is set to 0 in the denormal case. I think this is only required because .NET does not store the leading bit on the significand. According to IEEE 754, it can be stored either way. It appears that C# has opted for dropping it in favor of a sign bit, though I don't have any concrete details to back that observation.

In any case, the actual code is quite simple. All that is required is to excise the 8 bits storing the exponent and test for 0. There is a special case around 0, which is handled below.

**NOTE:** Per the comment discussion, this code relies on platform specific implementation details (x86_64 in this test case). As @ChiuneSugihara pointed out, the CLI does not ensure this behavior and it may differ on other platforms, such as ARM.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-120, denormal? " + IsDenormal((float)Math.Pow(2, -120)));
            Console.WriteLine("-126, denormal? " + IsDenormal((float)Math.Pow(2, -126)));
            Console.WriteLine("-127, denormal? " + IsDenormal((float)Math.Pow(2, -127)));
            Console.WriteLine("-149, denormal? " + IsDenormal((float)Math.Pow(2, -149)));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool IsDenormal(float f)
        {
            // when 0, the exponent will also be 0 and will break
            // the rest of this algorithm, so we should check for
            // this first
            if (f == 0f)
            {
                return false;
            }
            // Get the bits
            byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
            int bits = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
            // extract the exponent, 8 bits in the upper registers,
            // above the 23 bit significand
            int exponent = (bits >> 23) & 0xff;
            // check and see if anything is there!
            return exponent == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
-120, denormal? False
-126, denormal? False
-127, denormal? True
-149, denormal? True
```

Sources:
[extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c-sharp)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number
http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Code adapted from:
[extracting mantissa and exponent from double in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389993/extracting-mantissa-and-exponent-from-double-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think your answer is implementation specific. See the update to my answer for the details.

Comment: Indeed it is @ChiuneSugihara. I did not consider portability. Thanks for calling it out.

Comment: No problem, I feel like you need a Ph.D. in these crazy things to understand everything that is going on with them. I am very curious as to what the use case is for needing to detect these complicated unicorns of numerical calculations. It seems like they are adding a lot of complexity and I am thinking there must be a simpler answer to whatever problem is it that they are trying to solve. All that said if they really do need to detect them I think your solution is effective as long as portability doesn't come into play.

Comment: @KevinBurdett thank you. In deed is a better approach to analyse the format itself.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding denormalized numbers are there for help with underflows in some cases (see answer to [Denormalized Numbers - IEEE 754 Floating Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140847/denormalized-numbers-ieee-754-floating-point)).

So to get a denormalized number you would need to explicitly create it or else cause an underflow. In the first case it seems unlikely that a literal denormalized number would be specified in code, and even if someone tried it I am not sure that .NET would allow it. <s>In the second case as long as you are in a `checked` context you should get an `OverflowException` thrown for any overflow or underflow in an arithmetic computation so that would guard against the possibility of getting a denormalized number. In an `unchecked` context I am not sure if an underflow will take you to a denormalized number, but you can try it and see if you are wanting to run calculations in `unchecked`.</s>

Long story short you can not worry about it if you are running in `checked` and try an underflow and see in `unchecked` if you want to run in that context.

**EDIT**

I wanted to update my answer since a comment didn't feel substantial enough. First off I struck out the comment I made about the `checked` context since that only applies to non-floating point calculations (like `int`) and not to `float` or `double`. That was my mistake on that one.

The issue with denormalized numbers is that they are not consistent in the CLI. Notice how I am using "CLI" and not "C#" because we need to go lower level than just C# to understand the issue. From *The Common Language Infrastructure Annotated Standard* Partition I Section 12.1.3 the second note (page 125 of the book) it states:

> **This standard does not specify the behavior of arithmetic operations on denormalized floating point numbers**, nor does it specify when or whether such representations should be created. This is in keeping with IEC 60559:1989. In addition, this standard does not specify how to access the exact bit pattern of NaNs that are created, nor the behavior when converting a NaN between 32-bit and 64-bit representation. **All of this behavior is deliberately left implementation specific**.

So at the CLI level the handling of denormalized numbers is deliberately left to be implementation specific. Furthermore, if you look at the documentation for `float.Epsilon` (found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx)), which is the smallest positive number representable by a float you will get a denormalized number on most machines that matches what is listed in the documentation (which is approximately 1.4e-45). This is what @Kevin Burdett was most likely seeing in his answer. That being said if you scroll down farther on the page you will see the following quote under "Platform Notes"

> On ARM systems, the value of the Epsilon constant is too small to be detected, so it equates to zero. You can define an alternative epsilon value that equals 1.175494351E-38 instead.

So there are portability issues that can come into play when you are dealing with manually handling denormalized numbers even just for the .NET CLR (which is an implementation of the CLI). In fact this ARM specific value is kind of interesting since it appears to be a normalized number (I used the function from @Kevin Burdett with `IsDenormal(1.175494351E-38f)` and it returned false). In the CLI proper the concerns are more severe since there is no standardization on their handling by design according to the annotation on the CLI standard. So this leaves questions about what would happen with the same code on Mono or Xamarin for instance which is a difference implementation of the CLI than the .NET CLR.

In the end I am right back to my previous advice. Just don't worry about denormalized numbers, they are there to silently help you and it is hard to imagine why you would need to specifically single them out. Also as @HansPassant mentioned you most likely won't even encounter anyway. It is just hard to imagine how you would be going under the smallest, positive normalized number in `double` which is absurdly small.

Comment: I don't think this is accurate @ChiuneSugihara. I was able to create denormalized floats using both literals and operations (cast from double, specifically). I did so without entering an unchecked context.

Comment: You are always in checked or unchecked whether you specify anything or not. Checked just means that IL codes will be emitted that also check for overflow whereas unchecked means that IL codes will be emitted that will not. There is a global setting for the build set through the presence or absence of the \checked compiler switch. Also as far as denormalized floats, I noticed that you were able to create them. I didn't say that you couldn't just that I wasn't sure and thought that you likely couldn't although clearly you can in some cases. This is implementation specific though.

Comment: Very informative! I did not consider portability. That explains why I could not find an official source that documents the binary layout of the float. I think your advice is sound as well, generally it is best to leave the CLR to deal with these types of abstractions.