# Numpy matrix multiplication with scalar results in negative zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I have a random nxn matrix `A` with floating points, then I call

```
X = np.eye(A.shape[0])
```

matrix nxn which has diagonal values (0 elsewhere)

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

now I want to multiply every even row with -2 so I do

```
X[0::2] *= -2
```

however it returns

```
 2  0  0  0
-0 -2 -0 -0
 0  0  2  0
-0 -0 -0 -2
```

Why do the zeroes have negative sign? Does this matter at all and if so is it possible to avoid having that?
Thank you

**SOLUTION**

As someone pointed out, the `np.eye` function returns float matrix by default, fixed by adding `np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=int)`

Comment: I cant reproduce the `-0` results. please provide a code of how you generate th `X` array. My guess is that those are floats of a very small number

Comment: This is [possible due to the IEEE-754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Formats). Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255293/in-ieee-754-why-does-adding-negative-zero-result-in-a-no-op-but-adding-positive . Put it shortly, you should not care much about negative zeros. I wonder if they could be sub-normal value though (strongly impacting performance).

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Negative zeros do not exist on nearly all platforms (all mainstream platforms use the C2 representation now enforced by some languages like C++). The only platform supporting that are completely obsolete weird platform that Numpy should not even support. I strongly believe this is not integers that are printed. A MWE is needed so to see that.

Comment: I reproduce this matrix by this a = np.random.rand(4,4) and X = np.eye(a.shape[0])

Comment: This is not an integer array but a floating-point one. You should use `randint` for integers.

Comment: @JérômeRichard the a matrix is not integer matrix - never said that, but then the np.eye should return identity vector, and that one should have just integers

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Note that you can answer your own question by posting an answer. This is actually encouraged on StackOverflow .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

As someone pointed out, the `np.eye` function returns float matrix by default, fixed by adding `np.eye(A.shape[0],dtype=int)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the numbers are `float` types so the '0' is not actually 0 but a very small number so when you multiply the number by `-1`, you actually multiplying the small number which can be negative. You can read about how floas are stored in memory in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/215126) post.

Comment: ´np.float` has a representation `np.NZERO == -0.0`

Comment: interesting, thanks a lot! But I thought that np.eye returns an identity matrix which has just integers in diagonal

Comment: *"the '0' is not actually 0 but a very small number"* This is actually *wrong* in this case. There is no reason for `np.eyes` to fill the matrix with non zeros values outside the diagonal. It would be silly. You can check the value is actually a 0 or -0 using just an exact comparison.