# Why does clang not optimize away adding 0.0 to a floating-point number?

Tags: assembly, optimization, floating-point, clang, negative-zero

Compiling the following code with clang 14.0.0 (x86-64, -O3)

```c
double f (double x)
{
    return x + 5.0 + 0;
}
```

results in

```
.LCPI0_0:
  .quad 0x4014000000000000 # double 5
f(double): # @f(double)
  addsd xmm0, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
  xorpd xmm1, xmm1
  addsd xmm0, xmm1
  ret
```

([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/33vo75qYY)).

In which situation does the sequence

```
  xorpd xmm1, xmm1
  addsd xmm0, xmm1
```

make any difference?

While I am aware that float constant folding without `-ffast-math` is no possible in general, I cannot see any reason why the `xord/addsd` sequence is needed: It does not change the bit pattern in `xmm0`, I cannot see how it could trigger an exception or have any other side effect.

Edit: clang's default is `-fno-rounding-math` ([see manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html)). So it is safe to assume `x + 5.0` never results in `-0.0` and thus `+0.0` can be considered a no-op.

Comment: Adding `+0.0` is not always a no-op for strict FP math, due to signed-zero semantics (`-0.0`).  IIRC, subtracting `0.0` is a no-op, and indeed, clang *does* optimize `x + 5.0 - 0` down to just an add.  https://godbolt.org/z/zEdbvdv6e

Comment: Ah, it covers the case ```x=-5.0;``` in case of rounding towards negative because in this case ```5.0 - 5.0```results in ```-0.0``` ....

Comment: Or maybe it's a missed optimization; if we change the source to do `x=-5.0` first, it turns into a `return +0.0;` with or without adding zero.  https://godbolt.org/z/TsG5E7ec9.  And `nextafter(-5.0, -Inf) + 5.0` wouldn't underflow to `-0.0`, so I'm not sure there's a way for `x + 5.0` to actually produce `-0.0`.  Perhaps with the rounding mode set to round towards -Inf?  (floor)?  I forget if clang assumes the current rounding mode is the default round to nearest unless told otherwise.  But anyway, if so this is clearly still the reason for that missed optimization.

Comment: Yeah, I checked on real hardware, and the `addsd` produces a `0.0`, integer zero bit-pattern.  This is a missed optimization at least for the default rounding mode, because the value we're adding 0 to can't be `-0.0`.  IDK if it's worth reporting this; seems like a serious corner case for LLVM to look for, most source code doesn't add a zero after another constant.

Comment: No, it is unlikely that somebody writes such code. But it could be the result of some automatically generated code or the output of macros or templates.

Comment: Yes, it could be, it has non-zero value, but it also costs compile-time to look for it.  I guess only in a case where you're already adding `+0`, though, which is already a special case.  So there's hopefully be no slowdown for the common case.

Comment: [Why does Clang optimize away x \* 1.0 but NOT x + 0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33272994) confirms that `-5 + 5` should produce `-0.0` in roundTowardNegative mode.  So the optimization is only allowed if clang can assume the default rounding mode.  (Or with `-fno-signed-zeros` to forget about those semantics: https://godbolt.org/z/KdeYqej3b)

Comment: But https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html says ```-fno-rounding-math```is the default. So clang could assume there is no round to negative. So ```5.0 - 5.0``` cannot be ```-0.0```.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was going to investigate next.  Yeah, missed optimization, then.  You can report it on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues.  Feel free to link this Q&A and/or quote some of my comments.

Comment: Oh right, [as Marc Glisse (GCC dev) points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272994/why-does-clang-optimize-away-x-1-0-but-not-x-0-0#comment74952587_33273367), optimizing away `- 0.0` isn't legal with `-frounding-math`, because it can change `+0.0` into `-0.0`.  https://godbolt.org/z/E9rcGj3ro confirms that current GCC and clang both handle it correctly.  But as Marc warns, it still doesn't correctly handle the case of the rounding mode changing within a function: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath.  e.g. doing common-subexpression elim across potential rounding-mode changes.

Comment: So anywhere that optimizing away `x - 0.0` is legal, so is optimizing away `x + 0.0` if `x` is the result of adding or subtracting a non-zero value.  (There might be corner cases like FTZ without DAZ, though: `-DBL_MIN` plus a small positive subnormal would flush to `-0.0`.  But other than that, I don't think it's possible for FP addition to underflow to zero, only produce zero exactly.  Thus the rule about giving +0.0 for a sum/difference of zero applies, except when the inputs were both negative zero.)