# How are denormalized floats handled in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, intel, sse

Just read this [fascinating article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314926/1294758) about the 20x-200x slowdowns you can get on Intel CPUs with denormalized floats (floating point numbers very close to 0).

There is an option with SSE to round these off to 0, restoring performance when such floating point values are encountered.

How do C# apps handle this? Is there an option to enable/disable `_MM_FLUSH_ZERO`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no such option.

The FPU control word in a C# app is initialized by the CLR at startup.  Changing it is not an option provided by the framework.  Even if you try to change it by pinvoking [_control87_2()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx) then it is not going to last long; any exception will cause the control word to be reset again by the exception handling implementation inside the CLR.  Which was written to deal with another aspect of the FPU control word, it allows unmasking floating point exceptions.  It will also be detrimental to any other managed code that will not expect global state to be changed like that.

Having no direct control over the hardware is an implied restriction when you run code in a virtual machine.  Not that this is at all easy to do in native code either, libraries tend to misbehave when they too expect the FPU to have the default initialization.  Particularly a problem with the exception masking flags, DLLs created with Borland tools have a knack for turning exceptions on, making other code fail that isn't written to deal with such an exception.  An extremely ugly problem to solve, the FPU control word is the worst possible global variable you can imagine.

This does put the burden on you to not let your floating point calculations go haywire like this.  Calculating with denormals almost always produces nonsense results, if not from the radically small values, then at least from the quick loss of significant digits.  Truncating values less than 2.2E-308 to 0 is up to you.  Yes, not very practical.  Perhaps it is okay for a program to deliver nonsense results a bit slower than normal :)

Comment: While I completely accept your answer that it can't be done, I do take issue with the trivialization of the issue Truncating of doubles may be rare; but it's awfully easy to denormalize Singles when performing audio processing (e.g. digital filters, delay lines, &c). Given that the performance hit is horrifying on x86 architecture, it would be awfully nice to request that denorm exceptions be thrown.Scalars have checked operations. Why not floats too?

Comment: Pinvoking _control87_2() just isn't a problem when the code is localized like that.  Use _DN_FLUSH, don't forget setting it back.