# Can compiler simplify an expression with doubles?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am reading code from [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/code/ci/release/tree/src/Math.cpp):

```
 template<typename T> T Math::AngRound(T x) {
    static const T z = 1/T(16);
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    GEOGRAPHICLIB_VOLATILE T y = abs(x);
    // The compiler mustn't "simplify" z - (z - y) to y
    y = y < z ? z - (z - y) : y;
    return x < 0 ? -y : y;
  }
```

where `T` is `double` and `GEOGRAPHICLIB_VOLATILE` is `volatile`.

And I wonder, are compilers allowed to "simplify" `z - (z - y)` to `y`, and is
that prevented by `volatile` or not?
If it is relevant, I am interested in the C++17 standard.

Checking the assembly for clang showed that without `volatile`
`-O3` doesn't cause the simplification of `z - (z - y)` to `y`.

On the other hand, icc simplifies the code in both cases: https://godbolt.org/z/rz7erdhev .
If volatile is used, it adds an extra read, but not any real calculations.

Comment: Does `z - (z - y)` simplify to `y` with -O3 and fastmath?

Comment: Also is there any point in having volatile on a local variable?

Comment: `z - (z - y)` was probably written to prevent [subnormal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9314534/1541563). I doubt it needs to be marked `volatile` in order to achieve that though.

Comment: Don't the rounding-errors inherent in floating-point math make it so that `y == (z-(z-y))` is not a true statement for many values of `y` and `z`?  (if so, it seems odd that a compiler would be allowed to assume it will be true when optimizing)

Comment: @beothunder Yes, it does: https://godbolt.org/z/Yez3rf3oh

Comment: ICC defaults to `-fp-model fast`.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a c++17 question, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `-ffast-math`.
Here is a simple demo:

```
$ cat main.c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x=argc+0.5;
    return x-(x-27.5);
}
```

First compile it with default floating point support:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 main.c -o main
$ objdump -S -D main > main.default
$ sed -n "296,310p;311q" main.default
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x=argc+0.5;
 4f0:   66 0f ef c0             pxor   %xmm0,%xmm0
 4f4:   f2 0f 2a c7             cvtsi2sd %edi,%xmm0
 4f8:   f2 0f 58 05 b8 01 00    addsd  0x1b8(%rip),%xmm0        # 6b8 <_IO_stdin_used+0x8>
 4ff:   00 
    return x-(x-27.5);
 500:   66 0f 28 c8             movapd %xmm0,%xmm1
 504:   f2 0f 5c 0d b4 01 00    subsd  0x1b4(%rip),%xmm1        # 6c0 <_IO_stdin_used+0x10>
 50b:   00 
 50c:   f2 0f 5c c1             subsd  %xmm1,%xmm0
 510:   f2 0f 2c c0             cvttsd2si %xmm0,%eax
}
 514:   c3                      retq
```

Now compile it *with* floating point fast support:

```
$ gcc -g -O3 -ffast-math main.c -o main
$ objdump -S -D main > main.opt
$ sed -n "308,314p;315q" main.opt
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double x=argc+0.5;
    return x-(x-27.5);
}
 510:   b8 1b 00 00 00          mov    $0x1b,%eax
 515:   c3                      retq
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this answers the question. OP asks if such optimization is allowed, not which option causes it.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard imposes no requirements **whatsoever** on the accuracy of floating-point operations.  Practical compilers, however, are aware of the significance of such code and provide **options** to control behavior-changing transformations to it.   GCC in particular defaults to preserving the code and provides `-funsafe-math-optimizations` for the alternative.